# Spring cloud task(composed Task) restart from the failed job

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I have a spring cloud composed task which has nearly 10 jobs . If any of the job fails from the composed task, I have to continue the flow from the failed job. For Eg: After launching the composed task, if 4'th job fails , I don't want to run again from 1 st job, I want to continue from failed job .

Spring cloud version I am using is 2.10.1.

Thanks in advance.

Is there any property we can set to achieve this functionality or any other way ?

Comment: Have you restarted the CTR job by, clicked to the `Job Executions` tab to view job executions and then select the failed composed task runner job and then click the `RESTART` button.

Comment: I tried the solution,  but it is restarting that failed job alone, next jobs in that composed tasks are not running. From the composed task, out of 10 Jobs.  My 4 th job failed. So I restarted from 4th, it only runs4 th job alone. Rest 6 jobs not running .Is there any property that we set to run automatically if we click failed job?